# Style reply form different than comment form

Tags: html, forms, css, comments

Is there a way to display (css and html) in a different way  the "reply" form and the main "comment" form?

Comment: I think you can target it with a specific CSS rule (`.commments .comment #respond`), and then you can hide or show fields that are otherwise visible or hidden. So changing the HTML is difficult (but not impossible if you switch the core JS file with your own), but maybe you can do everything you want in CSS? Can you specify what you want to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it is the same form, but it is moved to another place in the DOM tree. So you could create one style for just `.comments #respond`, and one for `.comments .comment #respond` for the moved reply form.

Comment: Yes! For me the working one is `li.comment #respond{ yourstyle }` (had to add a .li). Was really under my eyes! Will look better at firebug next time! I'm learning so much stuff here...thanks Jan!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but: No, it's exactly the same form, just placed somewhere else via JavaScript.

Comment: Well, it is the same form, but it is moved to another place in the DOM tree. So you could create one style for just `.comments #respond`, and one for `.comments .comment #respond` for the moved reply form.

Comment: Smart, Jan! Works even better with `.comment #comment { /* whatever style definitions */ }`

Comment: I moved it to an answer - feel free to get your [Vox Populi badge](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/badges/68/vox-populi)!